# How to convert numeric values which are not Epoch Seconds to YYYY-MM-DD format in Big Query

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have one numeric field in Big Query which has few values like (8082320, 8162320, 8182320) .But these values are not epoch seconds or Timestamp_Seconds. How to convert these type of values to YYYY-MM-DD format in Big Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach

```
with data as (
  select 8082320 val union all
  select 8162320 union all
  select 8182320
)
select *, (
    select parse_date('%Y%m%d', string_agg(x, '' order by [3, 4, 2, 1][offset(offset)]))
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all('0' || val, r'\d\d')) as x with offset    
  ) as date
from data
```

with output

[image]

and yet another option :o)

```
with data as (
  select 8082320 val union all
  select 8162320 union all
  select 8182320
)
select val, parse_date('%Y%m%d', right(x,2) || substr(x,5,2) || left(x,4)) date
from data, unnest(['0' || val]) x
```

with same output

Pick whatever you like more :o)

Answer (score 1):

Below example should give you an idea

```
with data as (
  select 8082320 val union all
  select 8162320 union all
  select 8182320
)
select *, (select format('%s%s-%s-%s', 
      x[offset(3)], 
      x[offset(2)], 
      x[offset(0)], 
      x[offset(1)]
    ) 
    from unnest(
      [struct(regexp_extract_all('0' || val, r'\d\d') as x)]
    )
  ) as date
from data
```

with output

[image]